# RSA communication between Javascript and Python

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, rsa, pycrypto, pidcrypt

I am working on a prototype, so it needs to use RSA between a Chrome Extension and a Python Server.

So far I was planning on using https://sourceforge.net/projects/pidcrypt/ and https://www.dlitz.net/. However, while I can get decrypt and encrypt to work as per the documentation, I cannot get one to decrypt each other's message.

Can someone please, either suggest libraries that interoperate or let me know if I am doing something wrong with this libraries?

From what I worked out, pidder uses RSA PKCS#1 encryption-style padding (type 2). From googling, I sort of worked out that it is the type that PyCrypto calls PKCS1_OAEP. I am not too sure, but I have tried the standard and the other one two.

Help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Javascript library (pidCrypt) uses PKCS#1 v1.5 for RSA encryption, not OAEP.

That is supported by PyCrypto (see [here](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/api/current/Crypto.Cipher.PKCS1_v1_5-module.html)). This is the example for encryption:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_v1_5
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Hash import SHA

message = 'To be encrypted'
h = SHA.new(message)

key = RSA.importKey(open('pubkey.der').read())
cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(message+h.digest())
```

And decryption:

```
from Crypto.Hash import SHA
from Crypto import Random

key = RSA.importKey(open('privkey.der').read())

dsize = SHA.digest_size
sentinel = Random.new().read(15+dsize)      # Let's assume that average data length is 15

cipher = PKCS1_v1_5.new(key)
message = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext, sentinel)

digest = SHA.new(message[:-dsize]).digest()
if digest==message[-dsize:]:                # Note how we DO NOT look for the sentinel
     print "Encryption was correct."
else:
     print "Encryption was not correct."
```

Note that PKCS#1 v1.5 encryption scheme is know to be **badly** broken.

Comment: You can use forge for the JS side, it supports OAEP: https://github.com/digitalbazaar/forge#rsa

Comment: @dlongley Can you please give a reference of implementation?

Answer (score -3):

Would it be possible to use a HTTPS ajax connection instead? That way, you have end to end encryption without needing to worry about it yourself.

Comment: As I stated in the question, no. I am tunnelling through another server so part of the message needs to be encrypted so the second server can verify it.

Comment: You could try these two ports of libsodium/NaCL: https://github.com/tonyg/js-nacl & https://github.com/dstufft/pynacl. They may interoperate although I've never used either.